# $f(z) = z^2\overline{z}$ is analytic in a subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find whether the function $f(z) = z^2\overline{z}$ is analytic in a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. That's what I did:

By letting $z = x+iy$ we have:

$$f(z) = z^2\overline{z} = (x^2-y^2+2xyi)(x-yi) = $$

$$x^3+ix^2y+xy^2+iy^3 = x^3+xy^2+i(x^2y+y^3)$$

Now, applying the Cauchy-Riemann condition, we have:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 3x^2+y^2$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = x^2+3y^2$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \rightarrow 3x^2+y^2 = x^2+3y^2 \rightarrow$$

$$2x^2 = 2y^2 \rightarrow x=y, x=-y$$

Therefore, the function **can** be continuous in the subset where $y=x$ or $y=-x$. Continuity of partial derivatives will tell us if that's true. But if we look at the partials, they are continuous everywhere, so the function is indeed differentiable in the region $y=x$ or $y=-x$.

Am I right?

Comment: @Andrew sorry I didn't understand what you mean with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider both of the Cauchy Riemann equations, which will limit your choices. Alternatively when $f$ is a differentiable function of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ then $f$ is complex diffrentiable when $\partial f/\partial \bar{z}=0$ which here becomes $z^2=0$ or $z=0$. It is a matter of taste (or definition) if one will say that $f$ is analytic at $z=0$. Normally, this requires being complex differentiable on an open set.

Comment: I think "complex differentiable" would be a better term than "analytic" here.

Comment: Agreeing with the first comment, I think analytic suggests too strongly that it can be developed in a powerseries to make using it for $z=0$ here suitable. For complex dfferentiable and maybe even holomorphic I'd agree it could be seen either way.

Comment: I agree. I have restated...

Comment: Indeed.  In fact, if$f$ satisfies $\frac{\partial f(z,\bar z)}{\partial \bar z}=0$, this is equivalent to its satisfying the CREs.